# What's the semantically correct tag for citing the photographer of an image?

Tags: tags

I have a blog that has posts that contain images.

The HTML for the images looks like this:

```
<figure>
  <img>
  <figcaption>Photo courtesy of ABC.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

However, when I checked [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption#:~:text=The%20HTML%20or%20Figure,its%20parent%20element.), I found that this use of `<figcaption>` for the photographer is incorrect:

> The HTML  or Figure Caption element represents a caption
>   or legend describing the rest of the contents of its parent 
>   element.

So then I tried to find an HTML tag that makes sense semantically for citing the photographer.

Another search revealed the `<cite>` tag, but according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite):

> The HTML Citation element () is used to describe a reference to a cited creative work, and must include the title of that work.

So what's the (a?) semantically correct tag for citing the photographer on an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no semantic HTML element for that.

In my opinion though, a citation is close enough to a caption, as a caption is just ["a few lines of text used to explain and elaborate on published photographs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_caption), and a citation is arguably a way to "explain or elaborate" on the photo. So IMO `figcaption` is okay to use for that purpose.

It seems like I'm not alone in that thinking:

> The `<figcaption>` element is the most appropriate place for the credit, as long as you word it in such a way that readers won't confuse it with part of the caption.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58819903/2234742

If you want to be very explicit about citing a photographer in a machine-readable way, you can always use structured data. But in practice, image structured data will be mostly ignored.

In practice, tiny parts of semantic HTML like this will not carry huge weight, so make a best-effort to use proper semantic HTML but don't overly worry about it either.